# Jquery : Sliding Puzzle Generator Giving Unsolvable Puzzles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

From my understanding, creating a solvable sliding puzzle has to follow these rules:

> A. If the grid width is odd, then the number of inversions in a solvable situation is even.
>
> B. If the grid width is even, and the blank is on an even row counting from the bottom (second->last, fourth-last etc), then the number of inversions in a solvable situation is odd.
>
> C. If the grid width is even, and the blank is on an odd row counting from the bottom (last, third-last, fifth-last etc) then the number of inversions in a solvable situation is even.

My generator counts the number of inversions and detects where the empty space is, and should reroll the puzzle if the solution does not follow these rules.

Jquery / javascript posted below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tds = $("td");
    var tileCount = 15;
    var gameStart = false;

    function countInversions(board) {
        var inversions = 0;
        $.each(board, function (index, value) {
            if ($(value).children("div").attr("id") === "empty") {
                return true;
            } else {
                var tileNum = $(value).children("div").attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '') * 1;
                $.each(board, function (index2, value2) {
                    if ($(value2).children("div").attr("id") === "empty" || index2 <= index) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        var tileNum2 = $(value2).children("div").attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '') * 1;
                        if (tileNum > tileNum2) {
                            inversions++;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        console.log(inversions);
        return inversions;
    }

    var scramble = function () {
        do {
            for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
                var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * tds.length);
                var ranNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * tds.length);

                if (ranNum === ranNum2) {
                    continue;
                }

                var td1 = tds[ranNum];
                var td2 = tds[ranNum2];
                var tile1 = $(td1).children("div");
                var tile2 = $(td2).children("div");
                $("#" + $(td1).attr("id")).html(tile2);
                $("#" + $(td2).attr("id")).html(tile1);
            }
        } while ((countInversions($(tds)) % 2 !== 0 && $("#empty").parents("tr").attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '') * 1 === (1 || 3)) || (countInversions($(tds)) % 2 === 0 && $("#empty").parents("tr").attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '') * 1 === (2 || 4)));
        gameStart = true;
    };

    function slide(tile) {
        if (gameStart === true) {
            var tileNum = $(tile).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '') * 1;
            var $tile = $("#tile" + tileNum).clone();
            var pos = $(tile).parents("td");
            var posNum = $(tile).parents("td").attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '') * 1;
            var y = posNum - 4;
            var x = posNum + 4;
            var $empty = $("#empty").clone();

            if ($(pos).next().children("div").attr("id") === "empty") {
                $(pos).next().children().replaceWith($tile.hide());
                $(pos).children().effect("slide", {
                    direction: "right",
                    mode: "hide"
                }, "fast", function () {
                    $(pos).children().replaceWith($empty);
                });
                $(pos).next().children().effect("slide", {
                    direction: "left",
                    mode: "show"
                }, "fast", function () {
                    victoryCheck();
                });
                addSlide(); //slide right
            } else if ($(pos).prev().children("div").attr("id") === "empty") {
                $(pos).prev().children().replaceWith($tile.hide());
                $(pos).children().effect("slide", {
                    direction: "left",
                    mode: "hide"
                }, "fast", function () {
                    $(pos).children().replaceWith($empty);
                });
                $(pos).prev().children().effect("slide", {
                    direction: "right",
                    mode: "show"
                }, "fast", function () {
                    victoryCheck();
                });
                addSlide(); //slide left
            } else if ($("#td" + x).children("div").attr("id") === "empty") {
                $("#td" + x).children().replaceWith($tile.hide());
                $(pos).children().effect("slide", {
                    direction: "down",
                    mode: "hide"
                }, "fast", function () {
                    $(pos).children().replaceWith($empty);
                });
                $("#td" + x).children().effect("slide", {
                    direction: "up",
                    mode: "show"
                }, "fast", function () {
                    victoryCheck();
                });

                addSlide(); //slide up
            } else if ($("#td" + y).children("div").attr("id") === "empty") {
                $("#td" + y).children().replaceWith($tile.hide());
                $(pos).children().effect("slide", {
                    direction: "up",
                    mode: "hide"
                }, "fast", function () {
                    $(pos).children().replaceWith($empty);
                });
                $("#td" + y).children().effect("slide", {
                    direction: "down",
                    mode: "show"
                }, "fast", function () {
                    victoryCheck();
                });

                addSlide(); //slide down
            }
        }
    }

    function victoryCheck() {
        if (countInversions($("td")) === 0 && $("#empty").parents("td").attr("id") === "td16") {
            gameStart = false;
            alert("You won. Winner.");
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

});
```

See [http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mdr/teaching/modules04/java2/TilesSolvability.html](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Emdr/teaching/modules04/java2/TilesSolvability.html) for a more detailed explanation of solviblity of tiles games.

Public Fiddle example :
http://jsfiddle.net/themonstersarecoding/rzmKA/

Comment: is there a question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your logic for checking if a puzzle is unsolvable is incorrect, and it is because when you check if the row with the empty tile is odd or even, you overlooked the part where it says "counting from the bottom". One way to fix this would be to change the "id" values for the `<tr>` elements so they count from the bottom.

Change to:

```
<table id="slidingPuzzle">
    <tr id="tr4">
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr3">
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2">
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr1">
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Good point, let me change this and see if it fixes it. Unfortunately checking to make sure it fixes the issue involves verifying it's solvable so I'll have to get people to do a few of them first. Thanks for the comment!